# How can i get url address using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl url address from `<a href=>`
But This site's `<href>` is #none. 
how can i crawl this url address?
I've already figured out a lot but i couldn't find tips.

like this

```
<a href="#none" onclick="goDetail(519975);">
title
<a>
```

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

html = urlopen('https://www.daegu.ac.kr/article/DG159/list')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

nameList = bs.findAll('td', {'class': 'list_left'})

for name in nameList: 
    print(name.get_text())
    print(name.get_url)
    print('\n----------------------------------------------')
```

Comment: The short answer is "you can't". You can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to automate a browser that will run the javascript triggered by the link

Comment: You might have to use a headless browser!

Comment: So I'm needed to use 'selenium' right?  I'll figure out that! Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the id from the onclick on to a base url (which is what happens for the `onclick` event). The first three links (without `onclick`) have a different base.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

base1 = 'https://www.daegu.ac.kr/article/DG159/detail/'
base2 = 'https://www.daegu.ac.kr/article/DG159'
r = requests.get('https://www.daegu.ac.kr/article/DG159/list')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
links = [base1 + a['onclick'].split('(')[1].split(')')[0] if a.has_attr('onclick') else base2 + a['href'] for a in soup.select('.board_tbl_list a')]
print(links)
```

Comment: Thank you so much first! Actually i'm super beginner for coding so I don't understand code well. I'll figure out. Thank you!

Comment: The a tags with the onclick attribute have an Id number. That id is added to a base string to form the url for the detail page for that course etc. The first 3 links however are actual partial urls without an onclick and just need the right alternative base string added. The code collects all the a tag elements in the section and checks whether there is an onclick attribute in the element. If there is it extracts, using split, the number and adds it to the end of the appropriate base, otherwise it extracts the href attribute and adds it to the alternate base.